# Using Gram-Scmidt to obtain an orthonormal basis for the column space

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, matrices

How would I use the method of Gram-Schmidt to obtain an orthonormal basis for the column space of the matrix?
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3 & 1 \\
-1 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
2 & 4 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 3):

Take first column vector, $v_1 =v_1' = (2, -1, 1, 2)$.Then take second vector, $v_2 = (3, -1, 0,4)$. Then from $v_2$ subtract the component of $v_2$ along $v_1$ and denote it by $v_2'$. i.e.
$$v_2' = v_2 - \frac{\langle v_1', v_2\rangle}{\langle v_1', v_1'\rangle} v_1'$$
Then again take $v_3 = (1,1,1,1)$ and subtract it's component of $v_1'$ and $v_2'$ from $v_3$ and denote it by $v_3'$.
$$v_3' = v_3 - \frac{\langle v_3, v_1'\rangle}{\langle v_1', v_1'\rangle} v_1-\frac{\langle v_3, v_2'\rangle}{\langle v_2', v_2'\rangle} v_2$$

You get the orthogonal system of vectors $v_1', v_2', v_3'$. Then finally normalize it, you will get set of orthonormal column vector and it is the orthonormal basis of your column space.